# Is there any overview/list/details about which CoD Ghosts modes can use which multiplayer maps?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

As the title says, is there any overview or list detailing which multiplayer maps can be played with which modes?

Judging by [this site](http://www.codghosts.net/multiplayer-maps/) there are 14 maps. Can all of these be used with the Safeguard modes, as an example?

I know that when I played one of the earlier CoD games, once when I tried out a new game mode I was dropped into a quarry level with construction buildings and big blockish (sand)stones type of obstructions that I had never played before so I'm, from that experience, assuming that not all the maps can be used with all the modes.

Comment: In previous games, you could play pretty much every game mode on every map in private matches as far as I remember.  You might be better off refining your question to, "Which maps are in which online queues?"

Comment: The site you provided doesn't list a posted date, which could be indicative of a continually building page. I have Free Fall but have yet to play it in multiplayer. I believe the standard maps (I.E. those on disk and NOT DLC) are only in the rotations.

Comment: @ColeBusby Pretty sure the Free Fall map is currently only in the Normal mode Moshpit playlist. So if Hardcore is your thing, you won't see it until Freefall is released to everyone (like Nuketown in Black Ops 2).

Comment: @Lyrical I havent had a ton of playing time (<6 hours) so I can honestly state I've just been in squads and extinction. Cranked has yet to have it show up. I should just join the mostpit then.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of all maps from the [Call of Duty Wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/). While every competitive map supports every game mode, the *last entry* under each major heading (excluding the bonus map) is exclusive to the Extinction game mode.

## Standard Maps

- **Chasm**
- **Flooded**
- **Freight**
- **Octane**
- **Overlord**
- **Prison Break**
- **Siege**
- **Sovereign**
- **Stonehaven**
- **Stormfront**
- **Strikezone**
- **Tremor**
- **Warhawk**
- **Whiteout**
- *Point of Contact*

## Bonus Maps

- **Free Fall**

## Onslaught DLC Maps

- **Fog**
- **BayView**
- **Containment**
- **Ignition**
- *Nightfall*

## Devastation DLC Maps

- **Behemoth**
- **Ruins**
- **Unearthed**
- **Collision**
- *Mayday*

## Invasion DLC Maps

- **Pharaoh**
- **Departed**
- **Mutiny**
- **Favela**
- *Awakening*

## Nemesis DLC Maps

- **Dynasty**
- **Goldrush**
- **Showtime**
- **Subzero**
- *Exodus*